# Why does the emissitivity of metals increase (a lot) with temperature?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, thermal-radiation

If we take a piece of metal (could be silver, nickel, platinum, copper, etc.) at room temperature, its emissivity is relatively low compared to that of a black body: about 0.05 vs 1.00.

However if any of those metals are heated up to about 1500 K, they will glow red, just like a wood (epsilon is about 0.9 at room temperature) chunk.

So it looks like metals have their emissivity $\varepsilon$ increasing from $\sim0.1$ to $\sim 0.95$ when the temperature rises from $\sim 300 K$ to $\sim 1500 K$. What is the reason for such an increase? What is/are the mechanism for this phenomenon?

Edit in response to a comment concerning the surface and possible oxydation of the metals. According to https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/emissivity-coefficients-d_447.html, the emissivity of tungsten is about 0.04 and between 0.03 and 0.35 when aged. Tungsten is used in old lightbulbs and oxydation is one thing to avoid, that's why they use an inert (low pressure) atmosphere surrounding the tungsten filament. So my question still holds.

Edit: In response to the comment that the premise of my question can be wrong because a low $\varepsilon$ can still mean a lot of power emitted (which is true) and whether I have data to back my premise up. Well, I found some data http://www-eng.lbl.gov/~dw/projects/DW4229_LHC_detector_analysis/calculations/emissivity2.pdf which sort of invalidate my premise, but not entirely.

From the above data, it is clear that in general $\varepsilon$ increases with temperature, but nowhere as close to 1 as I thought. Platinum for example goes from $\varepsilon = 0.05$ to $0.10$ from $T =200°C$ to $600°C$. So we can expect an even higher emissivity at $1500 K$, probably around $0.20$ (or slightly more) by extrapolating the data from a Pt wire. Still, that's a relatively big increase in $\varepsilon$, so my question still holds.

I do not have time to copy and paste data for other metals, but you can take a look and these characteristics hold for many other metals.

Comment: This is an interesting question, but the premise may be wrong. Polished gold maintains a low emissivity (<0.05) even up to 2000F/1300K. I think that oxidation and chemical processes play a big role here more than anything else.

Comment: @KF Gauss I've edited my question to address your comment.

Comment: Do you have any evidence beyond simple visual observations (i.e. something quantitative) to back up the existence of this effect? The intensity of emitted light [scales as $T^4$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan%E2%80%93Boltzmann_law) for a *constant* emissivity, so the amount of light emitted always changes dramatically with temperature. Are you sure that the effect you are describing is substantially more than this?

Comment: @BySymmetry I've edited my question to reply to your comment (that moderators will unfortunately probably wipe out).

Comment: Nonetheless this question is interesting and worth investigating! I'll have to think about this some more